# How to Create a Sequence Diagram in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise from existing code?

Tags: uml, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to the Ultimate/Enterprise line of Visual Studio products, and one thing I was looking forward to was the easy creation of sequence diagrams based on source code.  Everything I've found says it's as easy as locating a method, and right click => Generate Sequence Diagram, as shown below:

[image: Generate Sequence Diagram]

...but this option doesn't seem to be available in 2015 Enterprise.  Did something change?

Comment: I'd have to check to be certain, but I remember that the move to Roslyn for the editor removed a lot of the infrastructure that powered the Generate UML features, and hence they were removed from the product. They may return, but they may also not.

Comment: Instead the Codemap feature is able to provide deep insight into the interrelationships between your code http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/02/23/code-map-improvements-in-visual-studio-2015-ctp6.aspx

Comment: Maybe this links help, not sure.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx ... but also check the architecture explorer is worth to mention

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As jessehouwing mentioned in his comment, generating sequence diagrams from code (and many other UML generation options) has been removed in VS2015.  With the current release, these are the diagrams that can be generated from existing code:

To visualize the architecture of a system **or existing code**, create the following diagrams:

- Layer Diagrams
- Code Maps
- Class Diagrams

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409436.aspx

Comment: Gerg, perhaps you mean removed in VS2017. Information at your "Source: " link seems to suggest this remains a feature of VS2015, i.e. "You can create the following UML diagrams in this release... UML Sequence Diagrams".

Comment: Wait! I see they ARE changing things... again. It's [Deja Vu all over again](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Visio/microsoft.public.visio.general/2008-05/msg00238.html)

Comment: @ScottWelker yes, 2015 allowed for creating sequence diagrams from scratch.  This question was in reference to generating sequence diagrams from existing code (which 2015 cannot do).  In looking into it a bit further...it appears they're removing UML designers altogether from 2017...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/what-s-new-for-design-in-visual-studio#uml-designers-have-been-removed

Answer (score -1):

Use this tool: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409377.aspx

Architecture menu, click New UML or Layer Diagram.

Comment: The "Architecutre -> New UML or Layer Diagram" menu option lets you create a new blank sequence diagram, but does not feature the option to generate one from existing code, which is what the OP is asking..

Answer (score -3):

It's only available in VS 2015 Enterprise Edition.

So you have to pay more money for those features.

Comment: not true, I have enterprise and can't generate either

Comment: Enterprise is the highest level of visual studio they sell. What else are they hiding? They used to sell Ultimate, but I don't see that listed anymore for 2015 on up.